# A monoid with left identity and right inverses need not be a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a set with an operation $\ast:G\times G \rightarrow G$ such that:

(1) For all $a,b,c \in G$ we have $(a\ast b)\ast c=a\ast (b\ast c)$ (associativity),

(2) There is $e \in G$ such that $e\ast a=a$ for all $a\in G$ (left identity),

(3) For all $a \in G$ there is $a^{\prime}\in G$ such that $a\ast a^{\prime}=e$ (right inverse).

Show that $(G,\ast )$ need not be a group.

I can't think of a counter example that satisfies this not being a group.

Comment: I think that the following is a really good start: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507279/example-of-left-and-right-inverse-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take e.g. $G = \{0, 1\}$ with $a, b \in G: a*b = b$. Then:
 - $*$ is associative
 - $b \in G: 1*b = b$, thus $1$ is a left identity
 - $b \in G: b * 1 = 1$, $1$ is always the right inverse

But this is obviously not a group

Comment: What's $b$ if $\{a,e\}=G$?

Comment: Corrected typo, sorry

Comment: @Squirtle: Either of the two members of $G$.

Comment: Looks to have gotten worse after the edit

Comment: Why? You can give different names to the same element...