# functions composition and surjective functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given  $$(f◦g)(x)=x$$ (from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ for any $x$ in $\Bbb R$)
**And $g(x)$ is onto!**

does it mean that also $$(g◦f)(x)=x$$

It seems like it does but how can I prove it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Surjections_as_right_invertible_functions

Comment: From [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064935/if-f%E2%97%A6gx-x-does-g%E2%97%A6fx-x) you know that $g$ is injective; add sujectivity to that and you know that there exist in inverse function $h$ such that $g(h(x))=h(g(x))=x$, next you show that $h=f$ and from this it follows that $g(f(x))=x$.

Comment: @Myself but I think that g is not injective at all

Comment: Either because you have learned it in some class, or because you are able to show it: for each $x$ there is a _unique_ $y$ such that $y=g(x)$. So the definition $h(y)=x$ makes sense. Then show, using this definition, that $g(h(x))=h(g(x))=x$.

Comment: @Myself I dont have a teacher I need to learn everything alone :( so I'll take it as axiom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following.

Since the map $g$ is onto, $x=g(y)$ for some $y\in R$. Then $$(g\circ f)(x)= (g\circ f)(g(y))=g\circ f\circ g(y)=g(y)=x.$$

Comment: Looks clean and good, how did you make the one before the last transition?

Comment: @TheOne $f\circ g(y)=y$ as given.

Comment: Oh didnt try to look at it that way thanks