# Does this injective function have an inverse?

Tags: functions

Suppose that $f: A \to B$ is injective, $A = \{5, 7\}, B = \{9, 10\}$ and $f(5) = 9$, $f(7) = 10$.

Now construct $g: B \to A | g(9) = 7, g(10) = 5$.

Does this function $f$ have a left inverse $g$, i.e. $g(f(a)) = a$ for all $a \in A$?

Comment: How can $f(5) = 9$ be if $9 \notin B$? Or $f(7) = 10$ if $7 \notin A$?

Comment: You have confused notation here. In your definition $f$ is not $A \rightarrow B$.

Comment: @MartinR please see edit.

Comment: @Alvis see edit.

Comment: $g(f(5)) = g(9) = 7 \ne 5$ and $g(f(7)) = g(10) = 5 \ne 7$

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. You *define* a function $f : A \to B$, and it is obviously a bijection. Hence it has an inverse $f^{-1}$, but it is not the function $g$ which you have defined.

Comment: @PaulFrost does it have a left inverse such that g is the identity map?

Comment: @lightxbulb That is not the definition of an inverse according to Dummit and Foote. a in A such that f(a) in C (a subset of B)

Comment: @JossieCalderon Where exactly did I define an inverse? The inverse would be $f^{-1}(9) = 5, f^{-1}(10) = 7$. If you're talking about the $g$, it was just to show that the claim $g(f(a))=a$ does not hold for any $a \in A$.

Comment: The problem in Dummit and Foote says if f is an injection, show f has a left inverse. You just helped me prove a counterexample, so are they wrong?

Comment: @JossieCalderon They are not wrong, I just defined the inverse $f^{-1}$. It's just that the $g$ you picked is not it.

Comment: Perhaps your question is this: Does every injective function $f : A \to B$ (where $A, B$ are arbitrary sets) have a left inverse $g : B \to A$?

Comment: @PaulFrost you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g(9) = 7, g(10) = 5$ is not an inverse to $f$, as you can easily verify by computing $g(f(5)) = g(9) = 7 \ne 5$. On the other hand both $g$ and $f$ are bijections so they have well-defined inverses:
$$f^{-1}(9) = 5, f^{-1}(10) = 7$$
$$g^{-1}(7) = 9, g^{-1}(5) = 10$$
If you want to construct an inverse to a discrete injective function $h:C\rightarrow D$ then $\forall c \in C : h(c) = d \in D$ define $h^{-1}(d) = c$. Then by construction the function $h^{-1}$ satisfies $h^{-1}(d) = h^{-1}(h(c)) = c$.

Comment: My error was in thinking that it was necessary for f to have a left inverse.

Comment: but why does f need to be one to one for it to hold true?

Comment: would this suffice? let f: A-> B, and a in A.

Then f(a) = b in B. 

Let g: B-> A s.t. g(b) = f^-1(b).

If f^-1(b) =/= a then two elements exist in the fiber of B, but that violates the claim that f is injective.

Thus f has a left inverse.

Comment: @JossieCalderon Well you have an inverse precisely because of the injectivity yes. If you want an example specific to right-left inverse: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507279/example-of-left-and-right-inverse-functions
Suppose that a function is not injective. That is you have $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $a_1\ne a_2$ but $f(a_1) = f(a_2) = b \in B$. Then you can't have an inverse function of this form, since it will violate the definition of function. However the inverse set mapping always exists (the set $f^{-1}(b) = \{a_1,a_2\}$, however that's a set and not a function anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Your question caused a lot of confusion. So let us prove the following which is probably that what you really mean:

A function $f : A \to B$ is injective if and only if it has a left inverse $g : B \to A$. Here, $A,B$ are any two sets.

1) Let $f$ be injective. Choose any $a_0 \in A$ and define
$$g : B \to A, g(b) =
\begin{cases}
a & b = f(a) \in f(A) \\
a_0 & b \in B \setminus f(A)
\end{cases}
$$
Note that by injectivity of $f$ for each $b \in f(A)$ there exists a *unique* $a \in A$ such that $b = f(a)$. By definition $(g \circ f)(a) = g(f(a)) = a$.

2) Let $g$ be a left inverse for $f$. If $f(a) = f(a')$, then $a = g(f(a)) = g(f(a')) = a'$. This means that $f$ is injective.